# Where is the designer view in WinUI 3?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I was developing uwp apps for the past few years, now moving to winui3. It is my first project. I am unable to find the designer view for the XAML files. Is it not available in WinUI3? or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unforturnately Designer View is not supported for now in WinUI3 for XAML files. You can track its status on Github:

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5917

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3656

Comment: Microsoft developers like us are pathetic. MS recommended us to go to WinUI3 from UWP. But even basic things are missing there.

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen Agree, things like that are really disappointing

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5917#issuecomment-1028626378) for more details. Seems like adding the XAML designer is no easy task.

Comment: It seems like nothing is easy in WinUI and C++/WinRT. UWP was amazing to use in many respects. I'm not getting the same feeling from the 'next generation'.

Comment: WinUI 3 still has no XAML designer (July 2022). What a glaring omission from a framework they seem so eager to get developers adopting.

Comment: Baffling decision by MS.  I was all set to start looking at WinUI for a new app.   No visual designer in Visual Studio?  Absolutely useless.   It's 2022, I'm not hand-crafting UI code guys, get real.

Comment: So, just found this (March 2023) as I was going to port from UWP, but no designer is pathetic and makes it a non starter. I'll find something else. @Swordblaster 's last sentence is bang on the money. We had better tools in the original Visual Basic.