# Visual Studio 2022 17.3.6 Xaml Designer not showing up for UNO platform

Tags: c#, uno-platform, xaml-designer

I've followed [Get Started on Visual Studio 2022](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-vs-2022.html) UNO platform guide. Then I've created new app with the following platforms:

[image]

When I try to open Xaml designer for **MainPage.xaml** - is is not appearing:

[image]

As you can I've selected WinUI project in a top-left dropdown as [adviced here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2772#issuecomment-598362590) - with no success.

How to make Xaml Designer appear?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the designer view in WinUI 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292470/where-is-the-designer-view-in-winui-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no XAML Designer for the new WinUI 3.0 (although there was one for the old UWP, which is what's referred to in the advice link that you found). So it's not exactly a problem of UNO Platform.

In fact, there is an open issue on GitHub which was opened more than a year ago, and the problem still remains:
[Discussion: WinUI 3.0 XAML Designer #5917](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5917)

And, apparently, it isn't even in the roadmap:
[Windows UI Library Overview](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/docs/roadmap.md)

Finally, there is a previous question here regarding this topic:
[Where is the designer view in WinUI 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292470/where-is-the-designer-view-in-winui-3)